# How can I control 8 LEDs with a timing delay with only one microcontroller (PIC12) written in Assembly?

Tags: microcontroller, led, pic, assembly, timing

I can have 5 I/O pins enabled. I'm just confused on how to control them individually.

Comment: It'll be easier to do if you add an 8 bit shift register like 74HC164 or 74HC595. It only requires 3 pins to control any number of LEDs using the 74HC164 once you daisy-chain more registers

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough I/O to drive each one straight from the microcontroller. There's two ways around this.

1) You need an external 3 to 8 (or 4 to 16) decoder which transforms your n I/O lines into 2^n I/O lines. [74154](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT154.pdf) or [74238](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT238.pdf) will do the trick. Downside: it's additional hardware, but the upside is it's very very easy to drive. Another option is 74595, which  are serial to parallel shift registers that can be daisy chained for effectively infinite I/O.

2) You can scan two banks of 3 LEDs using 2 control lines and 3 data lines. The control lines connect to the negative ends of the LEDs while the data lines connect to the positive. It looks like a grid where your control line are on the X axis, data on they Y axis, and LEDs wherever the two lines intersect. You turn on LEDs 1 to 3 by pulling Control 1 low so there can be a potential difference across them and Control 2 high so LEDs 4-6 stay off. Whatever LEDs you want on you turn high on the data line. You then take control 2 low and control 1 high and you set your data lines to turn on LEDs 4-6 while forcing LEDs 1-3 off. Since you wanted only 5, just don't put in a 6th in the second bank. You alternate fast enough so that it's imperceptible to the eye. This doesn't need anything external but its harder to do in software.

Make sure you have current limiting resistors!

Comment: So I have to use another logic chip , there's no getting around it?

Comment: Not if you're willing to scan across two lines. Ifyou want to drive all 5 simultaneously you need more hardware

Answer (score 2):

If you can use all 5 I/O pins, it should just be able to drive 8 LED's. The way to do this is very similar to the what Bamako describes using 2 control lines and 3 data lines. The trick is to use only 1 control line and 4 data lines. However to make this work you have to mount the LED's of the two 'banks' in opposite direction: one bank has their anodes connected to the data lines, the other has their cathodes connected to the data lines. The remaining pins of the LEDs are then connected to the 'control' line. Setting the control line high then lets you control one set of LEDs (setting the data lines low for the LEDs you want to turn on). Setting the control line low lets you control the other set of LEDs (setting the data lines high to make them light up).

For some reason the built in schematic editor doesn't load for me, so here an external picture. (Please ignore that these are regular diodes not LEDs - the principle is of course the same.) Of course you would want current limiting resistors on these lines as well.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, this is a really good idea. Simple and elegant

Comment: You can drive even more using Charlieplexing.